# Regex for Removing Duplicate HTML Tags in Python

Tags: python, html, regex, replace

I would like to reduce

```
<p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p> abcabc </p><p>
</p><p> defdef </p><p>
 </p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p> xyzxyz
```

to

```
<p></p> abcabc </p><p>defdef</p><p></p> xyzxyz
```

I try:

`str.replace('</p><p>+', '</p><p>')` and

```
re.sub('</p><p>+', '</p><p>', str)
```

Both no luck, any advise as to the way to do? Many thanks.

Comment: What's the logic in the result that you want? What is the condition when `<p></p>` should be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach: you can solve it with an *HTML parser*, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The idea is to find all `p` elements except the first one and remove them from the tree:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = "<p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>"

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: for p in soup('p')[1:]:
   ...:     p.decompose()   

In [5]: print(soup)
<p></p>
```

Or, you can find the first `p` element and remove all the next `p` siblings:

```
In [6]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [7]: for p in soup.p.find_next_siblings('p'):
   ...:     p.decompose()  

In [8]: print(soup)
<p></p>
```

Updated solution for the updated problem (cleaning up `p` elements with an empty text):

```
In [10]: data = """<p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p> abcabc </p><p>
    ...: </p><p> defdef </p><p>
    ...:  </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p><p>
    ...: </p> xyzxyz"""

In [11]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [12]: for p in soup.find_all("p", text=lambda text: not text.strip()):
    ...:     p.decompose()
    ...:     

In [13]: print(soup)
 abcabc <p> defdef </p> xyzxyz
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your solution works in the way of my specified text. Sorry for confusion. Actually there is some text in the string I want to remove duplicate. I have edited the questions to reflect the actual situation. Solution by using sub or replace would be appreciated.

Comment: @CL.L okay, I've updated the answer - please see if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import re

a="""<p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p> abcabc </p><p>
</p><p> defdef </p><p>
 </p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p><p>
</p> xyzxyz"""

print re.sub(r'</p><p>(?= ?</p><p>)', r'', re.sub(r'\n', r'', re.sub(r'<p>\n?</p>(?![ \w]+)', r'', a)))
```

Output:

```
<p></p> abcabc </p><p> defdef  </p><p></p> xyzxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the previous answers were removed, but one of that hits the point with the following code:

```
str1= re.sub(r'\n', r'', re.sub(r'<p>\n?</p>(?![ \w]+)', r'', str1))
```

it can actually further simplify to that:

```
str1= re.sub(r'\n', r'', re.sub(r'<p>\n?</p>', r'', str1))
```

Credits should be given that person if who posts that answer again.

Comment: Well that was me but it doesn't gives you what you have asked in the question. And don't keep the variable name as `str`, it masks the builtin class `str`

Comment: Check now. Perhaps this answer will be closer to what you have put in the requirement.